# Rendering Data in Table After each record processing completes

Tags: java, javascript, spring-mvc

I am creating a Spring MVC3 base web application . 
The application takes as an input two Dates . 
Now for all the records which lies in that date Range , I need to run the compare utility that I have written and will display the comparison result on GUI .

Now , the number of records is fairly large. Hence I don't want that user waits untill application get processed . 
Instead I want to display the comparison result on GUI, as soon as it gets finished for the record.

Please suggest , efficient way to do this.

Comment: you can initiate the code as a thread so that the processing happens in background and your users don't have to wait as soon as the thread is done with processing configure it to return the message. But you will have to take additional care while handling threads.

Comment: Why not just use an ajax call?

Comment: I have never used ajax call , so don't have any idea regarding that . Along with , even if I initiate my request with threads , but still the same view needs to be called by multiple threads. I am not very clear about this.

Comment: I think you have to implement the pagination in you'r application so that the limited set of records (i.e. page-size 50) will be fetched and processed.

Comment: ofcourse multiple threads with call the same view that's why I mentioned you'll have to take extra care while doing this.

Comment: @priyas Then now is the time to learn. Plenty of resources on the net. I prefer jQuery personally. If you aren't trying to optimize execution by parallel processing I'd stay clear of multiple threads.